# Javascript post request leads to following error: ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)

Tags: javascript, post

I'm trying to learn about HTTP Post requests, here's my code:

Client Side:

```
const options = {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(data)
                };
fetch('/api', options).then(response =>{
     console.log(response);
});
```

Server-Side:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('listening at 3000'));
app.use(express.json({limit: '1mb' }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/api', (request, response) => {
    console.log('I got a request!');
    console.log(request.body);
    const data = request.body;
    response.json({
        status: "success",
        latitude: data.lat,
        longitude: data.lng
    });
});
```

It leads to the following error on my localhost console:

[ERR_ABORTED 405 (Method Not Allowed)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v0TrO.png)

And it is complaining about the "fetch" line on the client side code. So there is an issue with the post. Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What URL do you have open in your browser?

Comment: your fetch URL is relative, so it's being sent to the server that served the page ... the error states the issue is with a request to 127.0.0.1:8080 ... but the server you think your posting to is listening on port 3000 ... so, your request is not being sent to the server you think it is ...

Comment: in other words ... the request should be sent to `"//????:3000/api"` - where ???? may be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` or ... who knows, you haven't supplied enough info for that - but at a guess it's one of those two (which mean the same thing anyway)